# Long running transactions in Slick

Tags: mysql, database, scala, slick

I'm working on a akka-http/slick web service, and I need to do the following in a transaction:

1. Insert a row in a table
2. Call some external web service
3. Commit the transaction

The web service I need to call is sometimes really slow to respond (let's say ~2 seconds).

I'm worried that this might keep the SQL connection open for too longer, and that'll exhaust Slick's connection pool and affect other independent requests.
Is this a possibility? Or does Slick do something to make sure this "idle" mid-transaction connection does not starve the pool?

If it is something I should be worried about - is there anything I can do to remedy this?

If it matters, I'm using MySQL with TokuDB.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't change order of the steps 1-2?

Comment: @igorpcholkin Yes. I'm calling that web service to create a sub-resource of the resource I'm inserting into my DB. So I need to either create both, or create none. Therefore, I need to rollback my transaction if the external web service fails.

Comment: Why not just 1/create your resource, release db query 2/ call service 3/ react to service result: if it worked do nothing, else delete what you created in step 1. (Because yes if the service get slower, it could definitely exhaust your  pool)

Comment: Because then, between steps 1 and 3, there's a resource in the DB that can potentially be queried in parallel, or deleted, or updated. Same reason why when you want to move money between two accounts, your bank doesn't 1/ credit account X, 2/ debit account Y, /3 if the previous step failed, take the money back from account X. All operations should be done atomically.

Comment: dcastro, sorry I still don't really get your logic. If you are using transactions, they are supposed to be isolated from one another until finished. I.e. other transactions are not supposed to see the row you inserted before commit. Do you intentionally rely here on less than `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level for some business logic? Or you do run queries including this row in the DB as a part of the same transaction?

Comment: @SergGr I *am* using transactions, yes. Are you referring to my [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811912/long-running-transactions-in-slick/47813332#comment82587775_47811912)? If so, I was merely replying to Esardes who suggested *not* using transactions.

Comment: @SergGr My only concern is that I may be forced to hold onto a connection/session while waiting for the external web service, and that my connection pool will starve.

Comment: @dcastro, I'm referencing to the first comment and your reply to it. Unless your web-service-call is a part of the same distributed transaction under some "distributed transaction manager" I don't see why changing the order of #1 and #2 and thus shortening the DB transaction is bad for you.

Comment: @SergGr oh my bad, I must have misread something. I thought Igor was suggesting reorder and not using a transaction at all. Re: your question, I need to insert a record in the db, then use the auto incremented ID to POST a sub resource to the external web svc (and roll everything back if the web svc fails)

Answer (score 0):

The slick documentation seems to say that this will be a problem.

> The use of a transaction always implies a pinned session.

And

> You can use `withPinnedSession` to force the use of a single session, keeping the existing session open even when waiting for non-database computations.

From: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/dbio.html#transactions-and-pinned-sessions